# Crystal reports filter out data on condition

Tags: filter, crystal-reports, formula, records

I have a report where I have multiple fields and I want to filter out records of a group on the basis of 2 fields and still show all the other records.

for eg I have 5 fields, the values of status are Open, Closed, Review.

ID       DATE         DESCRIPTION          STATUS         ACTION

I have grouped the report on the basis of STATUS. I want to show the records for the group STATUS = CLOSED with DATE after 2013/08/01 only, and show all the other records.

Comment: and still show all the records for Open and review

Comment: Have you thought about writing a formula to change the background color of the rows that are closed and date after 2013/08/01? That way you could still see the other records but it would highlight the rows meeting that condition?

Comment: That is a good idea, but we just needed to show the required data. Appreciate your idea and help. thanks